# Inverse Laplace transform of $1/\sqrt{P(s)}$ with $P(s)$ a polynomial of degree 4

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform, contour-integration

I am trying to compute the inverse Laplace transform of 
$$F(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{[(s+\lambda_3)^2-(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2][(s-\lambda_3)^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2]}},$$
where we can assume that $\lambda_3>\lambda_2>\lambda_1$.

If the polynomial was of order 2, the inverse Laplace transform would involve a modified Bessel function. However, here I am stuck.

By playing with the integral contour in the complex plane, I managed to rewrite the inverse Laplace transform as
$$
f(t)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}\left(\frac{e^{(\lambda_3+a \cos\theta)t}}{\sqrt{(a \cos\theta+2\lambda_3)^2-b^2}}-\frac{e^{(-\lambda_3+b \cos\theta)t}}{\sqrt{(b \cos\theta-2\lambda_3)^2-a^2}}\right),
$$
with $a=\lambda_2+\lambda_3$ and $b=\lambda_2-\lambda_3$. The arguments of the square roots are always positive.

Is there a way to compute this integral ? I would expect some Bessel function to come out of it, but I have no idea how to proceed.

A non-trivial thing is that the polynomial is invariant under exchange of the $\lambda_i$'s, and so should be $f(t)$. This is clearly not explicit in my integral representation, so maybe there is a better representation to use...

Comment: Since your function $F$ is the product of two functions whose inverse Laplace transform you know (Bessel function), you could use the property of the Laplace transform that it transforms convolutions into products. This way you would get your solution as the convolution of two (modified) Bessel functions. I am not sure if there is a closed expression for those, or if it helps you in this case, though.

Comment: This is indeed a possibility, but unfortunately, this is how I obtained $F(s)$... in order to compute explicitly this convolution of Bessel functions.